Why are spicy curries red in color
Most curries that are spicy have a red color, does it come just from adding chili powder.

Try some Thai Green Curry...

There are curries from all over the world.  Some are red.  Some are green.  Some are neither red nor green.  Some are spicy.  Some are not spicy. One can have a very mild red curry.  Once can have a very spicy green curry.  Color is not an indicator of spiciness and neither are all red curries spicy. Further, there are many potential ingredients that contribute color to curries, a few are spicy. Not all of the ingredients that contribute spiciness are red.
